# How to get Rect of titlebar buttons (minimize, maximize, close) using VCL styles

Tags: delphi, vcl-styles

How can I obtain the TRect for a form's minimize button when using VCL styles?

[image]

Comment: Using SO's search brings up https://stackoverflow.com/a/479507/4299358 which suggests issuing [WM_GETTITLEBARINFOEX](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/menurc/wm-gettitlebarinfoex)

Comment: I'm not sure that this approach will retrieve the correct results when used with VCL styles.